Prevent screen dimming on Low Power Mode on macOS
When Low Power Mode is enabled on macOS, the screen seems to dim (even if the "Slightly dim the display on battery" option is disabled in Battery settings). However, when low power mode is disabled again, when the power adapter is reconnected, the display does not go back to its original brightness. For example, I might be at 100%, on LPM it goes down to 60%, and when LMP is disabled again the brightness goes up to 80%.
This is quite inconvenient for me because I sometimes work on a train where the power goes out for a few seconds pretty regularly. This causes my display brightness to fluctuate pretty significantly over the course of the train ride, which is a major annoyance. Is there any way to disable this screen dimming while being on low power mode?
